# Prove the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ is not contractive

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Prove the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ is not contractive

I tried to prove this by contradiction but it didn't work.

By definition $x_n$ is contractive if there is a $c ∈ (0, 1)$ such that $|x_{k+1} − x_k| ≤ c|x_k − x_{k−1}|$ for all $k > 1$.

Comment: what is "contractive", can you explain?

Comment: xn is contractive if there is a c ∈ (0, 1) such that
|xk+1 − xk| ≤ c|xk − xk−1| for all k > 1

Answer (score 1):

Suppose otherwise it is a contractive sequence, then:

$\left|\dfrac{1}{k+1}-\dfrac{1}{k}\right| \leq c\left|\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k-1}\right| \to c \geq \dfrac{k-1}{k+1}, \forall k \to c \geq \displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} \dfrac{k-1}{k+1} = 1$, contradiction the condition that $0 < c < 1$.

Comment: Could you explain this step:
c≥limk→∞k−1k+1=1

Comment: Sorry I meant why does c have to be greater than or equal to the limit.

Comment: Divide both sides of the first inequality by $\left|\frac1k-\frac1{k-1}\right|$.